# Codeigniter HMVC - Two modules passing the same variable name to their views and causing conflict

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, hmvc

I have two modules in my installation. Both modules' controllers pass a variable called

```
$data['content']
```

to their views. Also, the first module's view runs the second module via

```
<?php echo Modules::run('module2'); ?>
```

and after that is supposed to display values from its $data['content'] variable. Unfortunately, that's when the first module's $data content is substituted with the second module's $data. This is pretty inconvenient for me, so I would like to know if there is a way to "protect" the $content variables and keep them only within their associated modules?

I would like to avoid renaming $data['content'] if possible. I've found a not-so-perfect solution in using

```
$data(__CLASS__)
```

but I am curious if it is possible not to change $data['content'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Some extends MX_Controller{

    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('template', array( //Primary template
            'content'    =>  'some_index' // index view
        ));
    }

    public function _module_1(){
      $this->load->view('module_1_view', array( //Module View : NO primary template
            ''    =>  '' <= no need to load view here, only data
        ));
    }

    public function _module_2(){
      $this->load->view('module_2_view', array( //Module View : NO primary template
            ''    =>  '' <= no need to load view here, only data
        ));
    }
}
```

-

**template.php**

```
<html>
  <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
</html>
```

-

**some_index.php**

```
<html>

//call modules
<?php echo Modules::run('some/_module_1'); ?>

<?php echo Modules::run('some/_module_2'); ?>

//call module from another class
<?php echo Modules::run('another_class/_module_1'); ?>

</html>
```